# How to get the result from a raw MySQL request in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to get the **number** (so an `integer`) of the MySQL `SELECT`'s per second in Laravel. Based from [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57418/how-to-determine-mysql-queries-per-day) I tried those, but it returns a `boolean`:

```
DB::statement('show global status like "Com_select"');
DB::unprepared('show global status like "Com_select"');
```

This returns `0`:

```
DB::connection()->getPdo()->exec('show global status like "Com_select"');
```

Doing the same query in the MySQL Workbench, I get:

```
+---------------+--------+
| Variable_name | Value  |
+---------------+--------+
| Com_select    | 818694 |
+---------------+--------+
```

How to get the return value of this kind of MySQL query using Laravel?

Thanks & cheers

Comment: Are you using the same credentials for Laravel you're using in Workbench? Or at least users who both have the correct permissions to access that information?

Comment: Yeah, same users, same permissions. `DB::connection()->getPdo()->exec('select count(*) from users');` returns `0` but this: `DB::table('users')->select(DB::raw('count(*)'))->get();` returns the same number like in the workbench.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$results = DB::select( DB::raw("show global status like \"Com_select\"") );

dd($results);
```

you can use this and result will be :

[image]

Comment: Waw... I thought that the `DB::select()` is only for `SELECT ...` queries... Thantks a lot, it works.